# How to use java jna on 64-bit windows?

Tags: java, jna, kernel32

I use java jna library (4.2.2 version), and i need to set system time in code. Here is my code:

```
Kernel32 kernel = Kernel32.INSTANCE;
WinBase.SYSTEMTIME newTime = new WinBase.SYSTEMTIME();
newTime.wYear = 2016;  // for example
newTime.wMonth = 10;
newTime.wDay = 10;
newTime.wHour = 10;
newTime.wMinute = 10;
newTime.wSecond = 10;
newTime.wMilliseconds = 15;
kernel.SetSystemTime(newTime);
```

This code works only in 32-bit windows, but it doest work on 64-bit system. What i have to fix to change correctly the system time in 64-bit system? Thanks.

Comment: Can you do this? `Kernel64 kernel = Kernel64.INSTANCE;`

Comment: In the library JNA there is no class Kernel64 ...

Comment: `SetSystemTime()` requires special privileges.  Are you sure it's a 32 bit vs. 64 bit issue, or perhaps an account permissions issue?

Comment: I believe that you can run 32-bit code on 64-bit if you are using a 32-bit JRE to execute it.